# How to align command output in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a command which gives me output like:

```
total time take                           11.1464s
```

I would like to print it like:

```
total time take=11.1464s
```

How can this be done in a shell script?

Comment: @pLumo Be careful, the `+ ` is extended RegExp syntax which `sed` by default doesn't understand unless backslash-escaped or called via `sed -r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
... | sed 's/   */=/'
```

or

```
... | sed -E 's/  +/=/'
```

or if it's not spaces but a tab:

```
... | sed -E 's/ \t+/=/'
```

(this works in GNU sed, but may not work in all versions of sed)

Comment: Thanks , this solution worked for me.

Comment: `\+` is a GNUism. Actually, that last one perhaps be `[ \t]{2,}`, since there's no guarantee the first character is space either.

Answer (score 1):

Piping whatever command displays that text through `sed`:

```
yourcommand | sed -r 's/ +([^ ]+)$/=\1/'
```

If it's a file:

```
sed -r 's/ +([^ ]+)$/=\1/' yourfile
```